# 500 Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\GitHub\maths4me\base.dust' with consolidate.js

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I get this error when trying to set up inheritance in dust.js:

```
500 Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\GitHub\maths4me\base.dust'
```

I have a file called index.html:

```
{>"base.dust"/}
   {<title}Hi{/title}
```

Which calls base.dust:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{+title}Maths 4 me{/title}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <p>Welcome to maths4me</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: need more info - how did you compile the two template files? because you may be referencing the partial wrong, but I can't be sure until I know more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dust partials look in the app root not the views folder, It took me some time to realise this. I was referencing a file in the wrong folder. My code should have been:

```
{>"/views/base.dust"/}
{<title}Hi{/title}
```

Comment: does not work for me: 500 Error: ENOENT, open '/views/base.dust'

Comment: {>"views/base.dust"/}
this works. forward slash causes error.

Answer (score 3):

`ENOENT` [means](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/b3e4fc6a48b97b52bd19de43c76b7082dcab4988/test/simple/test-domain.js#L73) that file doesn't exist.

Check again that `base.dust` exists in provided location.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me don't want to specify full paths to base templates and partials all the time, try out: [klei-dust](https://npmjs.org/package/klei-dust). (it's like consolidate but only for dustjs-linkedin)
In your scenario above you could just specify:

```
{>base/}
```

Instead of:

```
{>"views/base.dust"/}
```

...to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your names of your files. For me, I have seen this error **Error: ENOENT,**  and I noticed that in one my main app.js, I wrote

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/plan.html');
});
```

when I in views folder,I renamed it to home.html, This error appears accordingly